# Errno 11 Resource temporarily unavailable Multiprocessing manager queue

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I am currently trying to create a queue that would be shared between processes, however I am getting an error as said in the title [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable.  However I am not sure what is going on, I have tried to implement a retry on it to see if it would resolve the problem however it did not.

```
OutputQ = None
WorkersPerCPU = 1
pool_size = mp.cpu_count() * WorkersPerCPU
pool = mp.Pool(processes=pool_size)
manager = mp.Manager()
while not OutputQ:
    try:
        OutputQ = manager.Queue()
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        print "retrying..."
        time.sleep(2)
pool.apply_async(KeepAlive, (a, b, OutputQ))
```

The exception fires when I try to allocate a queue.

Comment: Try declaring your shared variables in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block?

Comment: @bbayles I am still getting the same thing

Comment: Did you get a solution to this